# Encryption password algorithms on OpenLDAP

Tags: encryption, md5, openldap, sha2

a question about OpenLDAP.
Where can I find some informations about OpenLDAP supported password encryption  algorithms on last version (2.4.35)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any such information. OpenLDAP doesn't encrypt passwords. It hashes them.